# Prob. 10, Sec. 3.2, in Erwin Kreyszig's "Introductory functional analysis with applications"

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products

Here is Prob. 10, Sec. 3.2, in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwin Kreyszig:

> ... Let $T \colon X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex inner product space $X$. If $\langle Tx, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in X$, show that $T=0$. ...

My Solution:

> For any $x, y \in X$ and scalar $\alpha$, we have
> $$ \big\langle T(\alpha x + y), \alpha x + y \big\rangle = 0. \tag{1}$$
> But using the linearity of $T$ and the properties of a complex inner product, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \  \big\langle T(\alpha x + y), \alpha x + y \big\rangle \\ 
> &= \big\langle \alpha Tx  + Ty , \alpha x + y \big\rangle \qquad \mbox{[because $T$ is linear]} \\ 
> &= \big\langle \alpha Tx, \alpha x \big\rangle + \big\langle \alpha Tx, y \big\rangle + \big\langle Ty, \alpha x \big\rangle + \big\langle Ty, y \big\rangle \\
> &= \alpha \overline{\alpha} \langle Tx, x \rangle + \alpha \langle Tx, y \rangle + \overline{\alpha} \langle Ty, x \rangle + \langle Ty, y \rangle \\
> &= \lvert \alpha \rvert^2 \langle Tx, x \rangle + \alpha \langle Tx, y \rangle + \overline{\alpha} \langle Ty, x \rangle + \langle Ty, y \rangle \\
> &= \lvert \alpha \rvert^2 \cdot 0 +  \alpha \langle Tx, y \rangle + \overline{\alpha} \langle Ty, x \rangle + 0 \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{[using the condition on $T$]} \\
> &= \alpha \langle Tx, y \rangle + \overline{\alpha} \langle Ty, x \rangle. \tag{2}
> \end{align}
> $$
> Using (1) and (2), we obtain
> $$ \alpha \langle Tx, y \rangle + \overline{\alpha} \langle Ty, x \rangle = 0. \tag{3} $$
> In the last relation, putting $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha = \iota$, respectively, we obtain
> $$
> \langle Tx, y \rangle +  \langle Ty, x \rangle = 0, \tag{4}
> $$
> and
> $$
> \iota \langle Tx, y \rangle - \iota  \langle Ty, x \rangle = 0,
> $$
> and this last equation upon dividing both sides by $\iota$ yields
> $$
>  \langle Tx, y \rangle -  \langle Ty, x \rangle = 0, \tag{5}
> $$
> Now adding (4) and (5), we get
> $$
>  \langle Tx, y \rangle = 0 \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X. \tag{6}
> $$
> But for each $x \in X$, the image $Tx$ also is in $X$; so we can put $y = T(x)$ in (6) to obtain
> $$
> \Vert Tx \Vert^2 = \langle Tx, Tx \rangle = 0 \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X,
> $$
> and therefore
> $$
> Tx = \mathbf{0} \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X, 
> $$
> Therefore we have shown that $T \colon X \to X$ is the zero operator, as required.

Is the above proof correct? If so, then where does the boundedness of $T$ come in?

Comment: This is perfectly correct; and the boundedness assumption is not necessary.

Comment: Why this is not necessary in real inner product??

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana the point is that for a real inner product space (where we don't have the scalar $\iota$), we can construct a non-zero linear operator $T$ such that $\langle T(x), x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $T$. For example, the operator $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(x, y)\mapsto(-y, x)$.

Comment: I got that point but, I am stuck at why rotation by 90° of the complex plane will not work as our non-zero transformation in the complex case?? @SaaqibMahmood

Comment: I mean just take your own function which you have just defined can't we extend that on the complex plane also??

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana no, it won't, and this is the whole point of this exercise problem. Please review my post once again, and you might be able to see what happens here.

Comment: I have gone through the proof many times but cannot figure out why ?? Explain please

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana and please do try to see the fact that although $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are considered to be identical for some purposes, they are not the same in all situations. So a linear operator $T \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is to be regarded as a complex inner product space, is not the same as a linear operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regarded as a real inner product space. Hence the difference in the situation.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana then we can chat over the phone through WhatsApp. My number is 00923345417958.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana please have a look at my post now. Do you find the proof any easier to follow now?

Comment: @qbert $T$ just has to be an everywhere defined linear map. You never use continuity in your (correct) proof.